# How can I share a root path using Express?

Tags: node.js, express, endpoint

I want to be able to have two endpoints sharing the root path, both for different purposes.
One will be for obtain a user via its ID and the other via token.

Right now I have the following routes:

```js
router.get('/:idUser', paramValidationRules(), validate, verifyJWT, getUserFromId);
router.route('/me').get(verifyJWT, getUserFromToken);
```

Running tests, the 'me' on the second route is considered a parameter and its redirected to the first route. Is possible to share a root path specifying that one will be used strictly to 'me' and the other one to an integer?

Comment: Using top level wildcard routes like `/:idUser` is not recommended.  That's specifically because it interferes with your ability to use any other top level routes and, even if you put the other routes first so they intercept the request before the wildcard, then you run the risk of an end user create a userid that conflicts with your top level routes.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're always hitting `/:idUser` before `/me`, so it will always stop at `/:iduser` and never react me.

So to solve the issue that you can never access `/me`, put the `/me` route declaration before `/:idUser`.

As to only catching numbers, there isn't a built in way, but you could use middleware (and change the order of your routes to the original):

```js
router.get('/:idUser', function(req, res, next) {
  req.id = /^\d+$/.test(req.params.idUser);
  next();
}, paramValidationRules(), validate, verifyJWT, getUserFromId);
```

Then, (unfortunately) in all your middleware and handler (or just the handler) in the opening of the function add:

```js
if(!req.id)
  return next();
```